# Project Euler Problem 1 - Multiples of 3 and 5

Tags: beginner, haskell, project-euler

I wrote this function for [Project Euler Problem 1](http://projecteuler.net/problem=1).

```
prob001 :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
prob001 a b = sum [x | x <- a, product ( map (x `rem`) b ) == 0]
```

The use is like this

```
GHCi> prob001 [1..999] [3, 5]
233168
```

But I am not at all satisfied with it. The list comprehension looks like something I have taken from Python. But I think the predicate can be much more efficient if it were written as a short-circuiting function. Currently it will have to evaluate each of these.

I am not able to think how to write that part in a short-circuiting way without a variable to hold the values. Am I correct in thinking that or not? Anything other that I can improve here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that `any` is your friend here.

```
aMultipleOf factors x = any (\f -> x `rem` f == 0) factors
prob001 :: (Integral a) => [a] -> [a] -> a
prob001 nums factors = sum $ filter (aMultipleOf factors) nums
```